# Activity having Spinner & Toggle Button

Tags: android, spinner, android-preferences, togglebutton

I am building one app & this is the setting page(Activity view) of my app is [*`this`*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6MIF.png).
I use one *`Toggle Button`* & *`Spinner`* .

When Toggle Button is checked the user profile is visible to all other users of this app & is Hidden when it is unchecked.

From Spinner options, user can search others users of this app around him/her by selecting distance.

What my problem is -> When app is running these settings working but when i relaunch my app user`s previous setting get lost(i.e., that are not persistent & again i have to do these settings)... How I can over come from this problem. My *code is->*

```
public class Settings extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener, OnItemSelectedListener  {
ToggleButton tgb;
Spinner redai;

final String[] dis_option= new String[]{"1 mile","5 miles","10 miles","All"};

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings);

  //Toggle Button
     tgb = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.settings_visibility);
     tgb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

  //Spinner 
    redai=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.settings_redai);
    ArrayAdapter<String> sel_dis=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, dis_option);
    sel_dis.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    redai.setAdapter(sel_dis);
    redai.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
        long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String temp_nearBy=parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

    /** preference that write the selected distance for further references in other Activities */
    SharedPreferences nearByDistanceWrite = getSharedPreferences("nearBy", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = nearByDistanceWrite.edit();
    edit.putString("upToDistance", temp_nearBy);
    edit.commit();
    Log.i("Settings_Spinner", "onItemSelected_pref_edited..."+temp_nearBy);
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (!isChecked) {
        buttonView.getContext(); 
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to Hide Your Profile?")
               .setCancelable(false)
               .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {


                     //here, I pass Visibility as '0' which means profile of fan is Hidden & not seen to other fans!
                       setVisibility(0);//Method which set Connection with sever & set the visibility of user profile accordingly 

                       /** Here you have to write code to set device token as '0' to hide the Profile of Fan! */
                       final ProgressDialog pg= ProgressDialog.show(Settings.this, "Progress...", "please wait updating settings!",true);
                       Toast.makeText(Settings.this,"Your Profile Set Hidden Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                      //setting toggle button to unchecked 
                        ToggleButton tg=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.settings_visibility);//buttonView.setChecked(false);
                        tg.setChecked(true); 

                        dialog.cancel();

                   }
               });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    } else {
        //here, I  pass Visibility as '1' which means profile of fan is visible to other fans
        setVisibility(1);
        Toast.makeText(Settings.this,"Your Profile get Visible Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();


    Log.i("Settings_onResume", "onresume_after(new)..."+nearBy);

}

/** Method that set connection with server & Set the visibility of Fan Profile to either Visible(1) or Hidden(0)
 * @param visibility : The int value which indicate to set profile of a Fan to be Visible or Hidden. */
private void setVisibility(int visibility) {
//...more code ...

 }

}
```

*How can i get these `Settings`(old settings or my previous settings) when i relaunch my app...???* &

*How can i make the `Spinner` view more eye catching & good looking(the system spinner is not looking good)???*

I *pleased* to have `pointers` or `code snippets` to solve this problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is for an app, you should be using your SharedPreferences to return these values. This is exactly what they are supposed to be used for. Accessing of data relevant to this specific app.

Comment: i am using SharedPreferences but problem is this when i relaunch my app the default settings replaces my previous settings. for ex. if i set my profile to hidden & distance to 5 miles then when i restart my app these settings get lost & again my profile is set to visible & distance to 1 mile??? which is the problem i am facing... Any solution or code please

Comment: This is a problem with how your code is writing to the values, fix this and then you'll solve the problem. You shouldn't be committing ANYTHING to the preferences unless the user has input it in the settings. If you are, you are not follow the standard configuration that is SharedPreferences.

Comment: i new to android. I am not getting how to set the Toggle button & Spinner to previous settings may i have any sample code or tutorial link which guide me to solve this problem @jox

Comment: You can Google this, tons of samples online.